# Не находит библиотеку Effects11.lib

Tags: c++, directx

Читаю книжку Луна (-ы ?), в общем, библиотеки в заголовке вопроса компилятор не нашел. Действительно, в папке с библиотеками я тоже её не нашел. Куда она могла пропасть и где её найти?

На компе семерка, VS 2013, DirectX SDK от июня 2010 года.

Comment: Надо же, а гугл это знает! http://fx11.codeplex.com/

Comment: Так значит надо было просто скачать и закинуть? Мда, стоит быть более самоуверенным.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что она нужна только для совсем древних 32-битных систем. Поэтому в новых SDK её отдельно нет, и поэтому MS выбросили её с исходниками на всеобщее растерзание.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Книга, видимо, до этого события была напечатана